# Accessing data attributes of element with Twitter Typeahead.js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, twitter-typeahead

I use Rails to generate my forms. I want to use Twitter Typeahead to autocomplete the fields with model associations.

The following CoffeeScript code:

```
console.log $('.typeahead').data('source')
```

works and returns:

```
["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

Can I access the same data from within the typeahead function? The following code:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead(
    name: 'test'
    local: $(this).data('source')
    console.log $(this).data('source'))
```

does not work and returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to save a reference to the jQuery object and use that instead of `this`:

```
$input = $ '.typeahead'
$input.typeahead
    name: 'test'
    local: $input.data 'source'
```

The problem is that `$(this).data('source')` is evaluated *before* it is passed to`.typeahead()`. At this point in time, `this` is still set to the global scope, which has no data attached to it.

Another option, which works even if you have multiple `.typeahead` elements, is to manually invoke `.each()` rather than relying on `.typeahead()` to iterate over the selected elements itself:

```
$('.typeahead').each ->
    $(this).typeahead
        name: 'test'
        local: $(this).data 'source'
```

This works because functions passed to `.each()` are "fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element" (see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)).

Comment: I believe this won't work in my pages with more than one .typeahead class. For now I use a workaround and duplicated the js code with unique id elements for each field I want to autocomplete. I have to do this for the whole site and this is not elegant but it works for now.

Comment: I have added an alternative where there are multiple `.typeahead` elements.

Comment: Fantastic. Exactly what I wanted to do. You rock!